# IFTTT | Ring Phone If Gmail subject is "XYZ"

Tags: ifttt

I'm using iPhone with gmail and IFTTT app.

I want to ring my phone when an email from gmail has subject "XYZ".

Is it possible?

I have searched IFTTT but unable to find such thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are no triggers for the Gmail service currently. This trigger only currently exists in IFTTT through the Outlook (Office 365 Business) service. Note that you'd have to sign up Office 365 Business, not the free personal version. You could access your Gmail account through Outlook (Office 365 Business) or forward emails from Gmail to a new Outlook (Office 365 Business) email account in order to effectively do this using IFTTT. Alternatively, you can try another integration app like Zapier which still has Gmail triggers such as the one you are looking for. However, there are limits to how often you can run an applet/zap under a free plan each month.